Why am I getting a "local variable 'connector' might be referenced before assignment" message?
Heres my code:
class AccountsDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            connector = sqlite3.connect('AccountsDB.db')
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            self.return_error(e)
        database_cursor = connector.cursor()

     @staticmethod
     def return_error(given_error):
        return given_error

When I hover over the word connector on line 7, I'm getting a message which says "local variable 'connector' might be referenced before assignment".
Can anyone help me or suggest a change in my code to remove it?

shouldn't your init function be called __init__ instead of __ init__?  Then what happens if an exception occurs? return_error is called which returns given_error that is then lost, since the return value is not assigned to anything. And then after return_error is called  the line database_cursor = connector.cursor() is executed, but Oh! connector doesn't exist because an exception occurred.

Calling self.return_error(e) does not return from and abort __init__! The return_error method is completely superfluous as is.

Since you assign the value to the connector variable inside a try-catch block, the code parser automatically assumes that there is a chance that sqlite3.connect function might fail (which is true). And if it fails, then the assignment of a value to the connector variable is failed too. And then on line 7, you are accessing a variable that is not defined, which raises NameError.
To fix this warning, you should either put your statement on line 7 inside a try block too:
def __init__(self):
    try:
        connector = sqlite3.connect('AccountsDB.db')
        database_cursor = connector.cursor()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        self.return_error(e)

Or put a return statement in the end of except block (to stop execution of the function and avoid line 7 being executed):
def __init__(self):
    try:
        connector = sqlite3.connect('AccountsDB.db')
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        self.return_error(e)
        return
    database_cursor = connector.cursor()


This will remove the possibility of NameError happening, which fixes the warning.
Also it seems like you have a misunderstanding about how return statement works. In Python (and almost all programming languages I'm aware of), return statement affects only the current method. So putting return in a separate method doesn't stop the execution of __init__ method, and the value that you returned is completely lost, because you aren't assigning it to any variable. If you want to return an error, you must do it in the __init__ method.
